# How to create dotted path from a text in html5 canvas (currently using phaser.io)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to create a dotted letter to represent a path on an html canvas, for example

```
function convertToDotttedPath(text, font) {

   return [{x: x0, y: y0}, {x: x1, y: y1}...] //to represent a path of text on a 2D canvas

}
```

Is there a library I can use? I would want to do this in code rather than manually using Adobe flash, like in the video below.

I'm trying to do this similar thing here but in canvas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xi25vodMYg0

Comment: This is a completely different question. I don't want to create my own font. What is described in the other question is a series of MANUAL STEPS! I don't want to do that. @Michael Radionov

Comment: My bad, the impression I got from your question was kinda similar to what is described in the other one. It is not my intent to mark or close the questions, but rather to help you find the solution. Maybe you could be more precise in what you need, because now it's a bit broad

Comment: If in your question you ask: `Is there a library I can use?` there's a high chance that your question will be closed... it is expected some coding effort on your side, Have you looked into `setLineDash` as an option ?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `setLineDash` it would draw a dotted letter or word...
Code is simple, something like this:

```html
<canvas id="c" width=600 height=160></canvas>

<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "150px Arial";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.setLineDash([3, 13]);
  ctx.strokeText("HELLO", 10, 120);
</script>
```

---

You can play with the font, lineWidth and LineDash values to get different results

```html
<canvas id="c" width=600 height=160></canvas>

<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "50px Arial";
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  ctx.setLineDash([1, 4]);
  ctx.strokeText("HELLO", 10, 45);
  
  ctx.setLineDash([3, 6]);
  ctx.strokeText("WORLD", 10, 90);
</script>
```

---

You can apply it to lines as well

```html
<canvas id="c" width=160 height=160></canvas>

<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
  ctx.translate(80, 80);  
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;

  function drawTriangle(size, angle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    size = size * 12
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      a = angle * Math.PI / 180
      x = size * Math.sin(a)
      y = size * Math.cos(a)
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      angle += 120
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  for (i = 20; i > 0; i--) {
    ctx.setLineDash([i, i/2]);
    drawTriangle(i, i*2 - Math.sin(i / 50))
  }
</script>
```

---

And using that same setLineDash you can do some fancy animations:

- https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvas_text_anim.html
- https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvas_text_flicker.html

Comment: This is great! Not exactly what I'm looking for since I'm looking to generate circles inside the text outline above. but this did give me an answer on how to do it! I could start from the top of the outline and start drawing circles that are equally spaced out.

Comment: @guest you realize that there was nothing about circles on your original post, right?